# Wi-fi stops after a while working. Issues related to supplicant network-manager

Tags: wireless, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

After a couple of hours of use my wifi disconnects.

While the network is working, if I do

```
sudo service network-manager status
```

There's no issue at all.
The device (wlo1) activation is "successful, device activated". and the supplicant is okay, saying "supplicant: wpa_supplicant die count reset".

Meanwhile, if I check the network manager status when is down. I've two warns.

The status explain in one hand

```
supplicant: failed to set WFD IEs on wpa_supplicant: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconneected from message bus without replying
```

And, in the other hand

```
device (wlo1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#1)
```

Any help really would help. Thanks.

Details of my wireless card:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 07
       serial: b0:5a:da:d0:bb:31
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:91004000-91004fff memory:91000000-91003fff memory:91500000-9150ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 18:4f:32:b6:95:3a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=5.0.0-20-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:121 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:91100000-91103fff
```

Edit: I already tried reinstalling network-manager but doesn't seem to work.

I'm using Ubuntu Disco Dingo 19.04

Comment: Mention the Ubuntu Version with your question!

Comment: Sorry, yeah. Thanks! I forget. I already edited. I'm using 19.03 Disco Dingo

Comment: Yes, Now I saw the version of Ubuntu. Did any minor update happen recently?

Comment: Sorry, it's .04. Not that I recall.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution in the web. I even wiped my hard disk and reinstalled Ubuntu. The problem persisted.

So. I changed the wifi chipset and now the wi-fi is working again. It seems like it was a problem more related to the hardware than the software.

Comment: What did you change the wifi chipset to? I am having a similar or possibly the same problem, except my wifi card is a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac. I had this problem since several Ubuntu versions (maybe since 18.10), but with older versions it was working normally, so I was surprised you concluded it was a hardware problem.